# Plot several graphs at the same time and changing options independently

Tags: plotting

I know that you can use `Map` and pure functions to avoid retyping commands in Mathematica. In the case of `ListPlot` this works as follows

```
ListPlot[#, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
   ImageSize -> Large] & /@ {list1, list2}
```

With this I get a list of the two plots of `list1`and `list2`. What I want to know is whether there is a convenient way to use this construction but change the options e.g. of `PlotLegends` independently for the two plots? If I simply specify `PlotLegends` in the `ListPlot` command it will be the same for the two distinct plots of `list1` and `list2`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Probably use `MapThread`. As an example `MapThread[
 ListLinePlot[#1, #2] &, {{list1, 
   list2}, {{Frame -> True}, {PlotStyle -> Red, Axes->False}}}]`.

Comment: Yes, comes close to what I was looking for. Nevertheless, I was hoping for some kind of a mixture of both: To write those options which are shared among both plots only once, but still have full control over the options that are different for the two plots. I think that is not possible, right?

`MapThread[
 ListLinePlot[#1, #2] &, {{list1, 
   list2}, {{ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> {"test1"}}, {ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> {"test2"}}}}]`

Here I need to repeat `PlotRange` and `ImageSize`.

Comment: That's no problem! Just put the extra options before or after the `#2`: `MapThread[
 ListLinePlot[#1, #2, Frame -> True] &, {{list1, 
   list2}, {{PlotStyle -> Blue}, {PlotStyle -> Red, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}}}}]`.

Comment: Sure, sometimes you don't see the wood for the trees. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. Only a tiny problem, but always looking for the most efficient ways :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use `MapThread`. As an example:

```
list1 = Range[10];
list2 = Range[10]^2;
```

Then, the options that they share can be put into the `ListPlot` call directly, and the options that they *don't* share are placed in the second list of the second `MapThread` argument:

```
MapThread[
  ListLinePlot[#1, #2, Frame -> True] &,
  {
    {list1, list2},
    {{PlotStyle -> Blue}, {PlotStyle -> Red, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}}}
  }
 ]
```

[image]